# Calling functions from internal packages

Tags: python, import, python-module, python-packaging

I've organized my project by separating different functionality, but don't how to communicate between the parts I've created.

I'm trying to access functions from `run_perf.py` in `addMetrics.py` by including this import statement

```
from analysis import run_perf
...
runtime = run_perf.calcMs()
```

Keep getting **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'analysis'** but don't know how to fix it.

### Project Structure:

```
myApplication/
│
├── bin/
│
├── myApplication/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── runner.py
│   ├── analysis/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── run_perf.py
│   │   └── mem_perf.py
│   │
│   └── conversion/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── convert.py
│       └── addMetrics.py
│
├── .gitignore
├── LICENSE
└── README.md
```

(If its worth noting, my `__init__.py` files are also empty at the moment)

Comment: It's in the way you run Python: cd into top level myApplication and execute `python -m myApplication.runner`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Received a very helpful message that fixed the issue!

```
I’m trying to access functions from run_perf.py in addMetrics.py by
including this import statement

from analysis import run_perf
...
runtime = run_perf.calcMs()

I keep getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘analysis’ but don’t know what about my import is wrong.
```

That means that Python can’t fine the “analysis” package. Python looks
in sys.path:

from sys import path
print(repr(path))

/Users/cameron/lib/python:/Users/cameron/rc/python

which contains my personal code and tabhistory for interactive python
use.

based on your file tree:

```
File Structure:

appName/
âââ bin/
âââ appName/
â   âââ __init__.py
â   âââ runner.py
â   âââ analysis/
â   â   âââ __init__.py
â   â   âââ run_perf.py
â   â   âââ mem_perf.py
â   âââ conversion/
```

[…]

You need to include /path/to/appName/appName in your $PYTHONPATH.

For testing purposes, do that by hand< example:

export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/appName/appName

For an appplication tree like the above, as installed, one typical
approach would be to have the executable in appName/bin be a small
wrapper script which figured that out from its own path, set
$PYTHONPATH, then executed Python on your real Python main programme. Or
alternatively to have the installation process wire the required path
into the wrapper script to avoid having it guess.

Cheers,
Cameron Simpson cs@cskk.id.au

https://discuss.python.org/t/calling-functions-from-packages/10107/2

Answer (score -1):

```
from myApplication.analysis import run_perf
```

Note that the package name *myApplication* violates PEP8 rules.

Comment: Just using _myApplication_ as an example, thanks for the heads up.

Your solution still resulted in the error:
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myApplication'**

Comment: This is based on the limited of information you shared with us. I assumed you're starting from within the top folder, but obviously you don't. So where is your top level script located and did you properly install your module in editable mode?